# nodeaccess prevent some roles to view views contents even if they allowed to access

Tags: users

I'm using [nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module to secure some published contents from being seen by normal users or anonymous.

I have a view allowed only to admin and moderator roles to access, but when nodeaccess module is enabled moderator role couldn't see the view contents.
the moderator have permissions to view and edit the content of this content type.

I tried to change the view permission access to "**view publish content**", it doesn't work until I disable nodeaccess.

So I want understand I what is them problem, and how can allow moderator user to view the view contents? Or at least if nodeaccess is not recommended in my usecase what I should do instead?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a module bug, you should check out the node access issue queue on its projects page on drupal.org. There are 41 open bugs there at the moment.

Comment: @Collins I'll do, but I seek for anlternative way to secure content, I don't have a lot of time.

Comment: have you tried granting your moderator role access to the published content that the view displays? So if your content type is "stuff" then you need to go to admin/config/people/nodeaccess and under the "stuff" category specifically allow moderator to view, edit and delete stuff. Then rebuild permissions admin/reports/status/rebuild and refresh all caches

Comment: @longboardnode yes I did

Comment: Are you going to be granting access to individual nodes? If not, you don't really need nodeaccess and you can just grant permissions from the core permissions page?

Comment: @longboardnode I just want to deny access some content types for some roles, the core permission view published content is applicable to all content type, that why I'm using nodeaccess. today I disabled nodeacces and I installed content access module, the problem persist, moderator can't  see view con't even if he can see exposed filters.

Comment: Weird... can moderator see the content directly if he goes to the node page itself?

Comment: @longboardnode yes he can, it's weird as you said

Comment: Yeah, it's quite strange, nodeaccess shouldn't be interfering with views permissions AFAIK. You might want to consider [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) as an alternative, it allows you to grant access by tags, so if you tag your content type with a certain tag, you can then allow moderator to view/edit all content with that tag and that shouldn't interfere with Views.

Comment: @longboardnode, I found this module node_view_permissions, it works well for me, so I'll remove nodeaccess, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this module [node_view_permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions), it did what I want in my use case, so I removed nodeaccess.

> Node view permissions module enables permissions "View own content"
>   and "View any content" for each content type on permissions page as it
>   was on Drupal 6. It's as simple as that.
>
> It's implemented in a non-conflict way, so you can use it with any
>   other permissions related module.